# Identification of processes that are not terminated by logging out

Tags: linux, security, process, process-management, crash

I'm trying to better understand how to terminate all undesired processes and start a Linux session fresh. By "undesired", I mean any processes left over from applications that have crashed.

Here's what happened:

I installed `Cairo-Dock` from a trusted source.  After using it for a while, it froze when, ironically, I clicked on its help icon the second time. Although I could have terminated it's main process, I wasn't sure if it had other processes running, so I decided to logout of the Linux session. After logging back in to Linux, I launched `Cairo-Dock` again.  I tried clicking on its help icon, and it froze again.

Again, I logged out of Linux and logged back in.  This time, after logging back in, I decided to delete all of Cairo Dock's configuration files, thinking one was perhaps corrupt. I then launched `Cairo-Dock` once again.  I tried clicking on its help icon, and it froze again. I then logged out of Linux and logged back in.  I noticed the system was sluggish.  I took a look at the running processes, and saw multiple `cairo-dock` processes eating up CPU cycles.  I manually terminated them all.

What I would like to learn is:

- Why didn't logging out terminate these processes?
- Unless one has memorized the process name of every process that *should* be running on their systems, how does one know if there are any wayward processes still running?  Obviously, if a wayward process is abusing the CPU all the time, it is easy to isolate, but if it isn't, how does one determine which, if any, processes are remnants of crashed/frozen applications?